# How to use Dictionary in a delegate

Tags: c#, dictionary, delegates

I have a Dictionary which I want to filter by different conditions, e.g.

```
IDictionary<string, string> result = collection.Where(r => r.Value == null).ToDictionary(r => r.Key, r => r.Value);
```

I would like to pass the Where clause as a parameter to a method that performs the actual filtering, e.g.

```
private static IDictionary<T1, T2> Filter<T1, T2>(Func<IDictionary<T1, T2>, IDictionary<T1, T2>> exp, IDictionary<T1, T2> col)
{
    return col.Where(exp).ToDictionary<T1, T2>(r => r.Key, r => r.Value);
}
```

This does not compile, though.

I have tried to call this method by using

```
Func<IDictionary<string, string>, IDictionary<string, string>> expression = r => r.Value == null;
var result = Filter<string, string>(expression, collection);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: Fixed return type. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Where` wants a `Func<TSource, bool>`, in your case `Func<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>, bool>`.

Furthermore, your return type of the method is incorrect. It should use `T1` and `T2` instead of `string`. Additionally, it is better to use descriptive names for the generic parameters. Instead of `T1` and `T2` I use the same names as the dictionary - `TKey` and `TValue`:

```
private static IDictionary<TKey, TValue> Filter<TKey, TValue>(
    Func<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>, bool> exp, IDictionary<TKey, TValue> col)
{
    return col.Where(exp).ToDictionary(r => r.Key, r => r.Value);
}
```

Comment: You could add a note that `Func<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` is needed because `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` inherits from `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`, but I already upvoted :-)

Comment: @DominicKexel: You just added that note yourself, I think that is sufficient :)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the constructor for the `Where` extension method you will see

`Func<KeyValuePair<string, string>, bool>`

So this is what you need to filter by, try this extension method.

```
public static class Extensions
{
  public static IDictionairy<TKey, TValue> Filter<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> source, Func<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>, bool> filterDelegate)
  {
    return source.Where(filterDelegate).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
  }
}
```

Call as

```
IDictionary<string, string> dictionairy = new Dictionary<string, string>();
var result = dictionairy.Filter((x => x.Key == "YourValue"));
```

Comment: That doesn't really do what the OP wants. Your `Filter` method doesn't add *any* benefit. The `Filter` method of the OP returns a filtered *dictionary*.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Okay I will add `ToDictionairy()` to the end, no problems :P